# Declaration of App\Models\User::isNot(App\Models\User $user)

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

i'm getting this error

> Declaration of App\Models\User::isNot(App\Models\User $user) should be
>   compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::isNot($model)

for my code here i'm using voyager package in laravel any idea how can i solve it

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User
 {


  public function isNot(User $user){
       return $this->id !== $user->id;
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defining a type hint you are changing the method signature compared to the original code you are overwriting.

See [Eloquent/Model](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1197-L1206):

```php
/**
 * Determine if two models are not the same.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null  $model
 * @return bool
 */
public function isNot($model)
{
    return ! $this->is($model);
}
```

In other words you probably want to have something like:

```php
public function isNot($user) {
    return $this->id !== $user->id;
}
```

or possibly:

```php
public function isNot($user) {
    if (!$user instanceof User) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Expected an instance of User');
    }
    return $this->id !== $user->id;
}
```

This solution is not ideal, but it ensures that you maintain the original method signature.